# why my multiple chart.js does not work properly?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have 3 Linechart in my page that get 3 different data ,when the page is loaded they're all fine but with scroll or click on stuffs all of them show the data of last chart(so they all look the same)
it's very confusing I'm not experimental with charts and I don't know how I can fix it.

here's my code

```
            async function createOrderChart (){
                var myLineChart = new Chart(ctxL, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                    labels: chartLabels,
                    datasets: [{
                    label: "Orders",
                    data: chartData,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        "rgba(140, 184, 179, .2)",
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        "rgba(214, 255, 250)",
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 2
                    },
                    ]
                    },
                    options: {
                        responsive: true        
                    }
                });
            }

            async function createTradeChart (){
                var myLineChart1 = new Chart(ctxL1, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                    labels: chartLabels,
                    datasets: [{
                    label: "Trades",
                    data: chartData,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        "rgba(219, 255, 251, .2)",
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        "rgba(219, 255, 251)",
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 2
                    },
                    ]
                    },
                    options: {
                        responsive: true        
                    }
                });
            }

            async function createUserChart (){
                var myLineChart2 = new Chart(ctxL2, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                    labels: chartLabels,
                    datasets: [{
                    label: "Users",
                    data: chartData,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        "rgba(224, 255, 251, .2)",
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        "rgba(224, 255, 251)",
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 2
                    },
                    ]
                    },
                    options: {
                        responsive: true        
                    }
                });
            }

            chartAjax("/api/",'m');
            ctxL = document.getElementById("orderChart").getContext('2d');
            createOrderChart();

            chartAjax("/api/",'m');
            ctxL1 = document.getElementById("tradeChart").getContext('2d');
            createTradeChart();

            chartAjax("/api/",'m');
            ctxL2 = document.getElementById("usersChart").getContext('2d');
            createUserChart();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all your charts use the same `array` for `labels` and also the same `array` for `datasets.data`. Each time, the `chartAjax` function is invoked, their content is overwritten.

To make this work, you could rewrite your code as follows. Providing the specific chart creation function as a parameter to the function `chartAjax`. When the ajax call is successful, `chartAjax` would then invokes the chart creation function with the correct data each.

```
async function chartAjax(url, interval, chartCreationFunction) {
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      'interval': interval,
    },
    success: function(response) {
      let resChart = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)); 
      let chartLabels = resChart.data.map(o => o['date']);
      let chartData = resChart.data.map(o => o['count']);
      chartCreationFunction(chartLabels, chartData);
    },
  });
}

function createOrderChart(chartLabels, chartData) {
  var myLineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("orderChart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: chartLabels,
      datasets: [{
        label: "Orders",
        data: chartData,
        backgroundColor: [
          "rgba(140, 184, 179, .2)",
        ],
        borderColor: [
          "rgba(214, 255, 250)",
        ],
        borderWidth: 2
      }, ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true
    }
  });
}

function createTradeChart(chartLabels, chartData) {
  var myLineChart1 = new Chart(document.getElementById("tradeChart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: chartLabels,
      datasets: [{
        label: "Trades",
        data: chartData,
        backgroundColor: [
          "rgba(219, 255, 251, .2)",
        ],
        borderColor: [
          "rgba(219, 255, 251)",
        ],
        borderWidth: 2
      }, ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true
    }
  });
}

function createUserChart(chartLabels, chartData) {
  var myLineChart2 = new Chart(document.getElementById("usersChart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: chartLabels,
      datasets: [{
        label: "Users",
        data: chartData,
        backgroundColor: [
          "rgba(224, 255, 251, .2)",
        ],
        borderColor: [
          "rgba(224, 255, 251)",
        ],
        borderWidth: 2
      }, ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true
    }
  });
}

chartAjax("/api/v1/admin/orderCahrt", 'm', createOrderChart);
chartAjax("/api/v1/admin/tradeChart", 'm', createTradeChart);
chartAjax("/api/v1/admin/userChart", 'm', createUserChart);
```

Comment: they're not the same, i edited my question and added my ajax code, could you check it again please?

Comment: @Zohre Zakariya: I updated my answer and hope this adds more clarity

Comment: thanks a lot, it works fine now. but has the same issue with interval changes. how can i delete the month data and then make the chart with week or day data?

Comment: @Zohre Zakariya: Seems to be a new issue. If you think, my answer solves your original problem, please accept it and post a new question for this new issue.